# How to customize the profile page in web2py

Tags: web2py

I am using web2py's default application. But I want to add some more fields in the profile page after login. I am not able to find how to add next text boxes in the profile page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the extra fields to be in the `auth_user` table, you can simply use the [`auth.settings.extra_fields` option](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09#Customizing-Auth). If you only want the extra fields to appear on the profile page but not the registration page, then you can conditionally set each field's `readable` and `writable` attribute depending on which action is requested:

```
def user():
    if request.args(0) == 'profile':
        for field in auth.settings.extra_fields['auth_user']:
            field.readable = field.writable = True
    return dict(form=auth())
```